# How to get the Height of a iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, attributes, height

I am struggling to get the height of a iframe. On this page: http://www1.voetbalzone.nl/inbeeld.asp?uid=321576&vztest=1

You will have to refresh a couple times to see the purple banner 300x600.

The purple image is wrapped in a iframe with the id=google_ads_iframe_/67970281/DISPLAY_OWNED__NL/Voetbalzone/Photos/Top_MPU_0" and their height="600".

I need to get the value of height, which is 600, but some of how I can't get access to the object. Probrarly there are multiple iframes and the iframe is not loaded fully yet. Ive tried a setTimeout, even that wont works.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
function makeYellow(){
$('#div-gpt-ad-1477555354937-3 iframe').css("border", "5px solid yellow !important");
}
setTimeout(makeYellow, 2000);
```

});

Can anyone help me please? thank you

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried, please?

Comment: well starting with to trigger the element:

$(document).ready(function() {
    function makeYellow(){
    $('#div-gpt-ad-1477555354937-3 iframe').css("border", "5px solid yellow !important");
    }
    setTimeout(makeYellow, 2000);
});

Comment: Thanks. It may be better though if you edited your question to include that code to make it easier for other visitors to find it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand you. Just edited my question and included the code. Will remember for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Well starting with to trigger the iframe:

$(document).ready(function() {
    function makeYellow(){
    $('#div-gpt-ad-1477555354937-3 iframe').css("border", "5px solid yellow !important");
    }
    setTimeout(makeYellow, 2000);
});

But even that wont work :/